# Optimizing SQL select

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, performance, oracle11g

Hi everyone I use visual studio with C# and oracle 11g database.

I have an application with a button that shows all data in a datagrid ordered by a certain date column. The problem is that this is taking too long, 20, to 30 seconds. I thought of limiting the search using the TOP in SQL but that isn't an ideal solution so I was wondering if you guys could help.

My issue is with this method:

```
public List<Adress> ListOprema()
    {
        string connectionString = "provider=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE; data source=ORCL; password=****; user id=****;";
        oleCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        List<Adress> _adressStore = new List<Adress>();


        try
        {
            oleComd = new OleDbCommand();
            oleComd.Connection = oleCon;
            oleComd.CommandText = "Select Oprema.Opr_Id, Oprema.Naziv, Oprema.Datum_Nabavke, Oprema.Datum_Zaduzenja, Oprema.Dobavljac, Oprema.Jedinica_Mjere,"+
            " Oprema.Zaduzio, Oprema.Vrijednost, Oprema.Kolicina_Nabavna, Oprema.Kolicina_Otpisana, Oprema.Kolicina_Trenutna, Oprema.Status, Oprema.Konto, "+
            " Oprema.KontoIsp, Oprema.Broj_Naloga, Oprema.Sifra_Objekta, Oprema.Sifra_Prostora, Dobavljaci.Naziv AS DobNaz, Radnik.Rad_Prez, Objekti.Objekat_ID"+
            " from OPREMA Oprema, DOBAVLJACI Dobavljaci, RADNIK Radnik, OBJEKTI Objekti"+
            " WHERE Oprema.Dobavljac=Dobavljaci.Dob_Id(+) AND Oprema.Zaduzio=Radnik.Rad_Id(+) AND Oprema.Sifra_Objekta=Objekti.Objekat_ID(+)"+
            " ORDER BY Oprema.Datum_Nabavke DESC";
            oleCon.Open();
            OleDbDataReader Reader = oleComd.ExecuteReader();

           while (Reader.Read())
            {


                int ix = Reader.GetOrdinal("DATUM_NABAVKE");
                int iy = Reader.GetOrdinal("DATUM_ZADUZENJA");
                int sifra =Reader.GetOrdinal("SIFRA_OBJEKTA");
                int sifraP = Reader.GetOrdinal("SIFRA_PROSTORA");
                int zaduzio = Reader.GetOrdinal("ZADUZIO");
                int prezime = Reader.GetOrdinal("RAD_PREZ");
                _adressStore.Add(new Adress()
                //_adressStore.Add(Adress.GetFromDataReader(Reader));
                {




                    Naziv = Reader["NAZIV"].ToString(),


                    //DatumNabavke = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["DATUM_NABAVKE"]),

                    DatumNabavke = Reader.IsDBNull(ix) ? DateTime.Now : Reader.GetDateTime(ix),

                    DatumZaduzenja = Reader.IsDBNull(iy) ? DateTime.Now : Reader.GetDateTime(iy),

                    //DatumZaduzenja = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["DATUM_ZADUZENJA"]),

                    InventurniBroj = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["OPR_ID"]),

                    Dobavljac = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["Dobavljac"]),

                    JedinicaMjere = Reader["Jedinica_Mjere"].ToString(),

                    Zaduzio = Reader.IsDBNull(zaduzio) ? null : (int?)Reader.GetDecimal(zaduzio),

                    Vrijednost = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader["VRIJEDNOST"]),

                    KolicinaNabavna = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["KOLICINA_NABAVNA"]),

                    KolicinaOtpisana = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["KOLICINA_OTPISANA"]),

                    KolicinaTrenutna = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["KOLICINA_TRENUTNA"]),

                    Status = Reader["Status"].ToString(),

                    Konto = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["Konto"]),

                    KontoIsp = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["KontoIsp"]),

                    BrojNaloga = Reader ["Broj_Naloga"].ToString(),

                    SifraObjekta = Reader.IsDBNull(sifra) ? null : (int?)Reader.GetDecimal(sifra),

                    SifraProstora = Reader.IsDBNull(sifraP) ? null : (int?)Reader.GetDecimal(sifraP),

                    ImeZaduzioca = (string)((Reader["RAD_PREZ"] == DBNull.Value) ? null : Reader["RAD_PREZ"]),

                    ImeDobavljaca = Reader["DobNaz"].ToString(),

                    IsNew = false,

                    IsReadOnly = true
                });



            }

            oleCon.Close();
            //} 
            //oleCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oleCon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return _adressStore;
    }
```

I ran the profiler and its reporting that these two lines are most expensive

Hot Path
Name    Inclusive % Exclusive %
Inventar.UserControls.SearchBar.SearchText_Changed(object,class System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs)   9,32    0,00
SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.DelegateMarshaler.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(object) 3,37    0,00

But that's because the SearchText_Changed calls the same function except with criteria and when there's no criteria it calls the above function (so when the search field is empty).

I also did autotrace in oracle's jdeveloper (in which the query runs really fast, but thats probably besides the point) and here are the results:

```
SELECT STATEMENT 
         22        

 SORT ORDER BY 
         22      972 

 NESTED LOOPS OUTER 
         20      972 

 HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER 
         20      61 

 Access Predicates 

 OPREMA.ZADUZIO=RADNIK.RAD_ID 

 TABLE ACCESS FULL 
 RADNIK      5       16 

 HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER 
         15      45 

 Access Predicates 

 OPREMA.DOBAVLJAC=DOBAVLJACI.DOB_ID 

 TABLE ACCESS FULL 
 DOBAVLJACI      3       7 

 TABLE ACCESS FULL 
 OPREMA      11      38 

 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN 
 OBJEKTI_PK      0       911 

 Access Predicates 

 OPREMA.SIFRA_OBJEKTA=OBJEKTI.OBJEKAT_ID
```

A friend suggested that I fill all my observable collections on application load and then search through the collections instead but I wouldn't know where to start with that, still a beginner.

Anyway I hope you guys can help.

Comment: I think you may improve reading performance by using numeric indexes in reader, and reading with appropriate Get method. for example reader.GetInt32(5)
This way you don't have to convert values.

Comment: Also you can use stored procedures and paging to limit data volume. This link may give you some idea about paging.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm

Comment: I'm trying to do the paging thing but the article on the site is for windows form and I am working with WPF so I tried that but:

    ds = new DataSet();
               adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
              adp1.Fill(ds, "Oprema");
              dg.DataSource = ds;
             dg.DataMember = "Oprema";

These lines are giving me problems cos there is no DataSource and DataMember properties in DataGrid (compared to DataGridView) so don't know how to do that

Comment: How would I bind the dataset to an ItemSource because that is the equivalent of DataSource in a datagrid but I can't set it to a dataset. It's giving me an error Cannot implicitly Convert System.Data.DataTable to IEnumerable are you missing a cast.

Comment: have a look at that http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#displaying

Comment: also you can look at the link below for stored procedures and paging idea. It is for asp.net but the concepts are the same. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Ok I've been debugging the bastard for the past 2 days so I am just seeing these links. Will take a look.

Thing is now I am thinking it is not the query. It is interesting because if I put a breakpoint in the query it doesn't fire when I press the button that shows the datagrid BUT if I change the query I can (slightly) change the amount of time it takes, I got it from 16 seconds to 10 with the most basic of queries that only takes the id and date (because I wanted to see if the order by date was causing the time trouble).

Comment: The problem seems to be from what I can gather in the getting the properties back for 2500 rows. So debugging it would go into the class property ID 2500 times and then Status 2500 times etc and that seems to be the issue more than the query itself. Even the query changes causing time changes could be more to do with the fact that changing the query to only get the ID changes also the amount of parameters to be gotten to only the ID. I dunno I am a beginner, very possibly talking absolute nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem isn't with the SQL it's with the Tabbed View and DataGrid. They don't seem to play well together.
Switching to ListView made it 60% faster. If I open a new window it's done in less than a second.
Thanks everyone for your help.